# React - The value prop is required for the <Context.Provider>. Did you misspell it or forget to pass it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have implemented a React context which listens to one document of my database when it is mounted.

```
function AccountStateProvider({ currentUser, children }) {
  const { signOut } = useSignOut();

  /**
   * Handles the current user's account deletion, signing out from the active
   * session.
   *
   * @returns {void} Nothing.
   */
  const handleOnAccountDeleted = () => {
    signOut(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser.data?.id) {
      return undefined;
    }

    //
    // Forces the logout of all active sessions on different mobile
    // devices after the user's account deletion.
    //
    const unsubscribe = onAccountDeleted(
      currentUser.data.id,
      handleOnAccountDeleted
    );

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [currentUser.data?.id]);

  return (
    <AccountStateContext.Provider>
      {children}
    </AccountStateContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

My purpose is to listen to this document in a global component which wraps the entire app... and I think that Context is a good tool for my use case.

The problem is that I am getting this warning:

> Warning: The `value` prop is required for the `<Context.Provider>`. Did you misspell it or forget to pass it?

Is it 'illegal' to use context this way without passing any value to the consumers?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: If you don't pass a value you don't need a context, you are using that component just like an HOC.

Comment: So, do you think I should move this code to a hook and use it inside one component of my protected routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would likely be better suited as a custom hook. Here's an example implementation:

```
function useAccountState(currentUser) {
  const { signOut } = useSignOut();

  /**
   * Handles the current user's account deletion, signing out from the active
   * session.
   *
   * @returns {void} Nothing.
   */
  const handleOnAccountDeleted = () => {
    signOut(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser.data?.id) {
      return undefined;
    }

    //
    // Forces the logout of all active sessions on different mobile
    // devices after the user's account deletion.
    //
    const unsubscribe = onAccountDeleted(
      currentUser.data.id,
      handleOnAccountDeleted
    );

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [currentUser.data?.id]);

  return null;
}
```